# Rubyで文字列と数字が混在している配列をソートする方法を教えてください

Tags: ruby

要素として文字列と数字が混在している配列があります。
これをすべて数字順に並べ替えたいのですが、どうしたらよいでしょうか？

たとえば、以下のような配列があったとします。

```
["123", 200, "12", 85]
```

これを次のように並び替えたいです。

```
["12", 85, "123", 200]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sort_by`メソッドを使えばソートできますよ。

```
["123", 200, "12", 85].sort_by{|item| item.to_i} #=> ["12", 85, "123", 200]
```

次のように書いても同じです。

```
["123", 200, "12", 85].sort_by(&:to_i) #=> ["12", 85, "123", 200]
```

Comment: ただし、 `nil` や `"dog"` といった数字以外の要素は `to_i` すると `0` として扱われるので、注意してください。

Comment: 文字列と数字の表現している値が整数であればうまく動くと思いますが、`.sort_by(&:to_i)`でソートすると`["1.5", "1", 2]`のような配列の場合、ソート結果は`["1", "1.5", 2]`にならず`["1.5", "1", 2]`になります。

Comment: `sort_by(&method(:Integer))`

Answer (score 6):

私は[Kernel#Integer](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/Kernel.html#M_-INTEGER)を使うのが好きです。

```
["123", 200, "12", 85, "dog", -5].sort_by{|item| item.to_i}
#=> [-5, "dog", "12", 85, "123", 200] >_<

["123", 200, "12", 85, "dog", -5].sort_by{|item| Integer(item)}
# ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "dog"

["123", 200, "12", 85, -5].sort_by{|item| Integer(item)}
#=> [-5, "12", 85, "123", 200]
```

次のように書いても同じです。

```
["123", 200, "12", 85, -5].sort_by(&method(:Integer)) #=> [-5, "12", 85, "123", 200]
```

([Object#methodのドキュメント](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/Object.html#I_METHOD))

Answer (score 4):

数値にマップして比較するのではなく、文字列にマップして比較する方法も考えられます。

```
ary = ["123", 'cat', 200, "12", 85, nil, 'dog']

p ary.sort {|a, b| format('%10s', "#{a}") <=> format('%10s', "#{b}")}
p ary.sort_by {|x| format('%10s', "#{x}")}

p ary.sort_by {|x| x.to_i}   # 数値にマップ
```

実行結果は次のようになります。

```
[nil, "12", 85, "123", 200, "cat", "dog"]
[nil, "12", 85, "123", 200, "cat", "dog"]
["dog", "cat", nil, "12", 85, "123", 200]
```